# Can I change the limits of compute resources of unscheduled pods, with a custom scheduler in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes-go-client

I am new to kubernetes and I am working on compute resource management of a kubernetes cluster. For this reason, I downloaded a toy scheduler (https://github.com/kelseyhightower/scheduler) in go. I know that once you set compute resource requests to pods you cannot change them. However, suppose that I have not set the resource requirements of the pod in the yaml file: e.g. nginx.yaml:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      schedulerName: hightower
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
```

can I apply resource requests for each pod that the custom scheduler tries to schedule?

Answer (score 0):

According to official Kubernetes [Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/), in order to manage compute resources in the cluster, you have to specify resource types like the maximum amount of `CPU` and `Memory` accordingly in the `Pod` or `Deployment` (if you consider making ReplicaSets) manifest file. Therefore, when you create `Pod`, `Scheduler` selects an appropriate `Node` for `Pod` to run on it, assuming that requested resources will not consume most of the `Node` capabilities.

Custom schedulers can extend the functionality and flexibility for the native Kubernetes scheduler; however, they can't change approach how to provision and manage resource requests or resource limits in Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the response, I agree that an implementation of a custom scheduler basically concerns how you bind the pods to nodes, however I thought that I could also enforce resources limits to pods (if there exist none), before the binding and when pods are waiting to be scheduled. It turns out that the only thing I could do is use deployments instead of pods and change the pod template of the deployment to apply also compute resource limits. This way is not as "clean" as I would like because the pending pods are destroyed and kubernetes spawns new ones that include the resource limits. If anybody is interested that is how I did it

```
imports ...
...

kubeconfig := clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(
        clientcmd.NewDefaultClientConfigLoadingRules(),
        &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{},
)
namespace, _, err := kubeconfig.Namespace()
if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
}
restconfig, err := kubeconfig.ClientConfig()
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}
clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(restconfig)
if err != nil {
        panic(err)
}

...

deploymentsClient := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments(namespace)
retryErr := retry.RetryOnConflict(retry.DefaultRetry, func() error {
    d, getErr := deploymentsClient.Get("deployment name",
         metav1.GetOptions{})
    if getErr != nil {
        panic(getErr)
    }
    d.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[0].Resources.Requests = 
        make(map[v1core.ResourceName]resource.Quantity)
    d.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers[0].Resources.Requests[v1core.ResourceCPU] = 
        *resource.NewQuantity("# of cores", resource.BinarySI)
    _, updateErr := deploymentsClient.Update(d)
    return updateErr
})
...
```